# getting the error Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in react while using arrow function

Tags: reactjs

iam new to react i tried to fix it by using bind method on my other projects. then i heard that binding is not required while using  arrow function. so i now trying to use arrow function but getting this error all the time

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button onClick={()=>this.props.handleIncrement(this.props.counter)}
   className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2 p-3">Increment</button>
  <button onClick={()=>this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)} className="btn btn-danger btm-sm">Delete</button>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
  
  formatCount(){
      const { value } = this.props.counter;
      return value === 0 ? "Zero" : value;
  }
  getBadgeClasses(){
    let classes="badge p-3 badge-";
    classes+= this.props.counter.value===0 ? "warning":"primary";
    return classes
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

i have imported counter into this counters.jsx.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from "./counter"

class Counters extends Component {
    state = { 
        counters :[
            {id:1 , value:2},
            {id:2 , value:0},
            {id:3 , value:4},
            {id:4 , value:0},
            {id:5 , value:5}
        ]
     }

     handleIncrement=counter=>{
         console.log(counter);
     }

     handleReset=()=>{

     }

     handleDelete=counterId=>{
        const counters=this.state.counters.filter(c=>c.id!==counterId);
        this.setState({counters});
     }
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                {this.state.counters.map(counter => 
                     <Counter key={counter.id} onDelete={this.handleDelete} 
                     onIncrement={this.handleIncrement} value={counter.value} id={counter.id} />       
                 )}
            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default Counters;
```

while compiling *iam getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined*
. i used arrow function instead of binding the function [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlDUm.png)

Comment: it seems you have passed only value in Counter, not the counter state,  

classes+= this.props.counter.value===0 ? "warning":"primary";

should be 

classes+= this.props.value===0 ? "warning":"primary";

Comment: You pass the counter value to the `value` prop, i.e. `value={counter.value}`, but then try to reference it via `props.counter.value`, which OFC will throw error.

Comment: while using classes+= this.props.value===0 ? "warning":"primary"; iam getting the error Cannot read property 'value' of null

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the prop as `value` but in the child component you're accessing it as `counter.value`.

`this.props.counter.value` should be `this.props.value`. Or else send the `counter` to the child.

Comment: i noticed it now but while changing it to this.props.value iam getting a new error called Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Oh then maybe one of the `value`s is `null`?... In the question, all the values have some numbers though. Maybe your actual code is different.

Comment: i copied it directly from vscode. let me check again

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

1. `counter.value` is passed to `value` prop of `Counter`, but accessed as `this.props.counter.value`.
2. `this.handleIncrement` is passed to `onIncrement` prop, but accessed as `this.props.handleIncrement`.
3. `this.props.handleIncrement` passes `this.props.counter` as argument, but both are undefined.

## Solutions

1. Access correctly `this.props.value`.

   ```
   formatCount() {
     const { value } = this.props; // <-- destructure correctly
     return value === 0 ? "Zero" : value;
   }

   getBadgeClasses() {
     let classes = "badge p-3 badge-";
     classes += this.props.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary"; // <-- access correctly
     return classes;
   }
   ```
2. I suggest converting your handlers in `Counters` to curried functions so you don't need to pass the `id` explicitly. I also suggest using functional state updates so counts are correctly updated from the previous state.

   ```
   handleIncrement = (id) => () => {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
       counters: prevState.counters.map((counter) =>
         counter.id === id
           ? {
               ...counter,
               value: counter.value + 1
             }
           : counter
       )
     }));
   };

   handleDelete = (id) => () => {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
       counters: prevState.counters.filter((counter) => counter.id !== id)
     }));
   };
   ```
3. Attach the modified handlers and access accordingly. Here we will pass the `id` value to the curried handler.

   Counters

   ```
   <div>
     {this.state.counters.map((counter) => (
       <Counter
         key={counter.id}
         onDelete={this.handleDelete(counter.id)} // <-- pass id
         onIncrement={this.handleIncrement(counter.id)} // <-- pass id
         value={counter.value}
       />
     ))}
   </div>
   ```

   Counter

   ```
   <div>
     ...
     <button
       onClick={this.props.onIncrement} // <-- attach handler callback
       className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2 p-3"
     >
       Increment
     </button>
     <button
       onClick={this.props.onDelete} // <-- attach handler callback
       className="btn btn-danger btm-sm"
     >
       Delete
     </button>
   </div>
   ```

[image: Edit getting-the-error-cannot-read-property-value-of-undefined-in-react-while-using]

Full Code

```
class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    const { onDelete, onIncrement, value } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{value}</span>
        <button
          onClick={onIncrement}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm m-2 p-3"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        <button onClick={onDelete} className="btn btn-danger btm-sm">
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getBadgeClasses() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    let classes = "badge p-3 badge-";
    classes += value ? "primary" : "warning";
    return classes;
  }
}

class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 2 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 4 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 },
      { id: 5, value: 5 }
    ]
  };

  handleIncrement = (id) => () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      counters: prevState.counters.map((counter) =>
        counter.id === id
          ? {
              ...counter,
              value: counter.value + 1
            }
          : counter
      )
    }));
  };

  handleReset = () => {};

  handleDelete = (id) => () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      counters: prevState.counters.filter((counter) => counter.id !== id)
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { counters } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {counters.map(({ id, value }) => (
          <Counter
            key={id}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete(id)}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement(id)}
            value={value || "Zero"}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```